# Plotly Dash side by side graphs

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I am trying to create a Dash dashboard with two plotly graphs side by side and one under them. Here is the code:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(2)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A', 'B', 'C'], data=np.random.rand(5,3))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A', 'B', 'C'], data=np.random.rand(5,3))
df3 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A', 'B', 'C'], data=np.random.rand(5,3))

def create_fig(df):
    data = go.Table(
        header=dict(
            values=[str(i) for i in df.columns],
            align='center'
        ),
        cells=dict(
            values=df,
            align = "left",
            height=45
            )
    )

    layout = dict(
        showlegend=False,
        width=200
    )
    return dict(data=[data], layout=layout)

app = dash.Dash(external_stylesheets=['https://codepen.io/amyoshino/pen/jzXypZ.css'])

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div(
        className="row",
        children=[
            html.Div(
                className="six columns",
                children=[
                    html.Div(
                        children=dcc.Graph(id='left-top', figure=create_fig(df1))
                    )
                ]
            ),
            html.Div(
                className="six columns",
                children=html.Div(
                    children=dcc.Graph(id='right-top', figure=create_fig(df2)),
                )
            )
        ]
    ),
    html.Div(
        className="row",
        children=[
            html.Div(
                className="twelve columns",
                children=[
                    html.Div(
                        children=dcc.Graph(id='bottom-bar-graph', figure=create_fig(df3))
                    )
                ]
            )
        ]
    )
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

I've tried a few different proposed solutions, but haven't had any success yet. I've tried changing the width and height in the layout of the figures as well.
[Tried solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61718173/plot-dash-chart-side-by-side)
[Tried solution 2](https://community.plotly.com/t/how-to-manage-the-layout-of-division-figures-in-dash/6484/2)

Answer (score 1):

[Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) will handle that no problem. The `div` you gave `className='row'` should have the `display: flex;` style in CSS, or `style=dict(display='flex')` if you're doing it inline.